# Custom Protocol Handler that does not "steal" focus

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, custom-protocol

There is a WinRT application that should access to some system information. There are some resources on the net that told that we can use Custom Protocol (WinRT application make a launch of the protocol and then desktop app is started and do some work). The Custom Protocol handler is c# desktop app (console application which "Output type" is set to "Windows Applicatoin" as we do not need any interface ).

So, the thing is: when WinRT app launches custom protocol, the desktop app is started and all stuff working correctly, but in that moment when desktop starts the main WinRT app is hide out for the time needed desktop app to work.

Is there some solutions, that allow to start desktop application in silent mode (don't know how to put that, "background" maybe), so that WinRT is showing itself all the time.

Comment: Probably there is solution with c++. Any approach will be acceptable.

Comment: You do know that such a setup won't be easy to deploy? The app in the store won't include the desktop part. You'll need to ensure that one some other way for your application to work. What work is the desktop app doing that can't be done from a Windows Store app but needs to be?

Comment: Yes, I understand the complexity of deploying such solution. Desktop app will do work related to the system (e.g. make WMI calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching it was decided to introduce *common file* which will be another (along with custom protocol) *communication level* between store and desktop apps. This approach allows desktop app to stay in the memory and listen to file changes during work of store app.

So the work is: if store app needs some system information it writes command to the file and desktop app, after performing all needed work, send information to the store app through custom protocol.